# WCF: ServiceClient + Dispose

Tags: wcf

This is what I understand from why we need to implement our own wrapper class for serviceClients (please correct me if I'm wrong):

> The purpose of catching the exception
>   in the Dispose() method is that
>   .Close() may throw either a
>   "CommunicationException" or
>   "TimeoutException" - and to prevent
>   the connection to hang you catch those
>   two exceptions to use .Abort() which
>   will change the state of the
>   communication object to closed
>   immediatley. - it would not make any
>   sense to let the exception be
>   unhandled because the nessecary calls
>   to the methods have already been made
>   since we're at the Dispose() part, and
>   it would therefore be odd to throw an
>   exception when the job actually is
>   done as it should.

But why do:

```
public class ServiceClientWrapper<TServiceType> : IDisposable
{
    public TServiceType Channel { get; private set; }
    private readonly ChannelFactory<TServiceType> _channelFactory;

    public ServiceClientWrapper(string endpoint)
    {
        _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<TServiceType>(endpoint);
        Channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        ((IChannel)Channel).Open();
    }

    #region Implementation of IDisposable

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            ((IChannel)Channel).Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ex)
        {
            ((IChannel)Channel).Abort();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            ((IChannel)Channel).Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ((IChannel)Channel).Abort();
            throw;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When you can do:

```
public class ServiceClientWrapper<TServiceType> : IDisposable
{
    public TServiceType Channel { get; private set; }
    private readonly ChannelFactory<TServiceType> _channelFactory;

    public ServiceClientWrapper(string endpoint)
    {
        _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<TServiceType>(endpoint);
        Channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        ((IChannel)Channel).Open();
    }

    #region Implementation of IDisposable

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ((IChannel)Channel).Abort();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

According to MSDN both `.Close()` and `.Abort()` will change the state of the communication object to "Closed"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that Close() will aim to close the entire communication channel gracefully, including any closing handshake required by the communication protocol, whereas Abort() is a rude and brutal tearing down of the client-side channel stack with no attempt to communicate the closure properly to the other side. Abort may therefore leave server-side resources still tied up on a connections which will not be used further.

So we always want to execute Close if possible, but we need to handle situations where things are so broken that trying to do a Close will cause a further exception.

Comment: Ah, I see. My thoughts about why one would implement his own wrapper class for serviceClient(s) is valid? or is it just a bunch of crap?

Comment: @ebb: I wouldn't be so rude as to say the latter... but as a rationale it is a little confused, shall we say :-). The main reason people write wrappers is because the standard pattern for consuming IDisposable objects, with a `using` block, gives incorrect and unintuitive behaviour for WCF clients in the face of exceptions, because the closing brace } of the using block will throw and hide the original causative exception in circumstances where `Close()` can't succeed.

Comment: ... and therefore people wrap the `Close()` inside a try/catch block and will handle `CommunicationException` and `TimeoutException` with `Abort()` since theres no reason for letting the exception be unhandled since that would cause the application to stop, and since we already have called the nessecary methods from the service and got the values returned theres no need to let the application stop - something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Close method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms405496.aspx

This method causes a CommunicationObject to gracefully transition from any state, other than the Closed state, into the Closed state. The Close method allows any unfinished work to be completed before returning. For example, finish sending any buffered messages.

Abort method
Does the same ungracefully or as stated in the specs immediately. It will NOT finish anything still going on...