# Object and a web service dependency

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, idisposable

I have a question about implementing the Dependency Injection pattern. I have a class that requires access to a web service. According to this pattern I shouldn't have my class instantiating the service as this causes a strong dependency with it. This lead me to creating a factory class that constructs my class and in its constructor passing the correct service it requires, i.e. dependencies.

What is troubling to me is that I am passing the instance of the web service client to my object but wouldn't this leave the service open?

Should I pass the entire client in as opposed to only the interface? This way I can implement IDisposable and close the connection to the service?

Thanks in advance.
Please feel free to correct any terminology, don't mean to cause confusion.

For example:

```
public class ProductService
{
    private IProductService client;

    public ProductService(IProductService client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void DoIt()
    {
        client.MyWebMethod();
    }
}

public class Factory
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T : class
    {
        T item = null;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(ProductService))
        {
            item = new CustomerService(**new ProducttServiceClient()**) as T;
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look into using a dependency injection framework, such as the [Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/) instead of rolling your own factories. This will save you time in the long run.

Comment: I am trying to avoid things like that. I am trying to understand the concept via doing this by hand. From some web searching I found examples where they pass in the ServiceClient NOT the interface and within the dispose method clean up resources..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you create instance yourself by `new ProducttServiceClient()`, then you/factory need to dispose it. That's the place where DI containers like Unity, Castle Windsor can help you and release/dispose it.

Assuming we are talking about generated service client ProducttServiceClient - subclass of ClientBase, please be aware, that if you dispose the client it will try to close opened and not aborted channels - which can lead to an exception.[See this link for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071183/wcf-serviceclient-dispose)

If you just pass in opened channel (System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.CreateChannel()), then you can close/abort it and reuse the client again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your factory class creates the service client instance, it should also be responsible for closing it. But what are you trying to achieve (except trying out dependency injection and the factory pattern)? I don't think the factory pattern gives you much in this case.

If you don't want your client to create and close the proxy every time you want to call a service operation I would recommend creating a extension method on ICommunicationObject that is responsible to do the work and then close the proxy. Then you only have to implement the logic for disposing your client once (and in one place!).

extension might look like this:

```
public static TResult Using<T, TResult>(this T client, Func<T, TResult> work) where T : ICommunicationObject
{
    TResult res = default(TResult);
    try
    {
        res = work(client);
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (CommunicationException)
    {
        client.Abort();
            throw;
    } // ... more catch cases might go here... 
    finally
    {
        if (client.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
            client.Abort();
    }

    return res;
}
```

your client would invoke the method like this:

```
using TheNameOfYourNamespaceDefiningTheExtension

return new ServiceClient().Using(client => client.MethodName(request));
```