# What's disposing my WCF objects and why?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have an app that uses WCF to communicate with a remote server. Frequently, and relatively predictably, I'm getting `ObjectDisposedException` showing up in my logs, and I can't figure out why. It appears that the WCF objects themselves have been disposed. So far, I've seen these object types disposed, and throwing exceptions:

- `System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory'1+HttpRequestChannel[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel]`
- `System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel`

I've gathered WCF tracing info, and every call that fails in this way follows the same pattern:

1. Trace Transfer, From
2. Activity boundary, Start
3. Message Log Trace
4. Throwing an exception
5. Trace Transfer, To

There's nothing in my code that's explicitly disposing service clients. In fact, I'm only passing around the service contract interfaces themselves, and they don't implement `IDisposable`, so it's unlikely that a `using` block, for instance, would be the culprit.

As I said earlier, it's relatively predictable that I can reproduce these errors; however, I can't get it to happen predictably with a specific service contract interface, let alone a specific method call on that interface. It moves around a bit. Sometimes the first call fails, sometimes it fails after a few calls.

I've already ruled out network connectivity issues. Is there anything I can do to isolate the source of these exceptions; i.e. the core reason why my `CommunicationObject`-derived objects are getting disposed, or is a special-case in my exception logging to treat these as benign my only option?

**Update:**

I'm using channel factories to create instances of my service contract interface. I'm not caching/reusing those channel factories. I also have some `IMessageInspector` implementations that are getting wired up via `IEndpointBehavior` and attached via `channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(...)`. I'm doing everything programmatically, rather than config-driven, and so there's a lot of code in play, hence it not being posted.

An example stack trace:

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.BeginRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.BeginRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartSend(Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishEnsureOpen(IAsyncResult result, Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartEnsureOpen(Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishEnsureInteractiveInit(IAsyncResult result, Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartEnsureInteractiveInit()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.Begin()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginCall(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeBeginService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
<truncated, my application-level code is at this level>
```

I've searched the web, I've decompiled WCF internals, I've debugged, gathered trace logs. I've done my homework. As you can see by the edit history, I've added detail every time someone has asked for it. If you have any contribution to add, including "you shouldn't do that," please do jump in.

Comment: How are you calling your service in code? Please post it.

Comment: I added some details. It really isn't feasible to post all the code.

Comment: When you call createchannel() and get a proxy, how are you disposing of that proxy?

Comment: I'm not, I'm leaving it for the GC to pick up.

Comment: Post the full exception ToString which is going to include the stack. Btw, not disposing your clients seems unsafe. The rules for when that is safe are not trivial.

Comment: I was under the impression that the rules for *disposing* clients weren't trivial, not vice-versa: https://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/using-and-disposing-of-wcf-clients/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071183/wcf-serviceclient-dispose appear to indicate that. Adding stack trace...

Comment: Yeah, WCF dispose pattern is broken. It is disgusting. But disposal is still a must until proven to be not necessary. And even then architecturally not always desirable to omit.

Comment: I would look for catches that silently swallows the original exception you might be having. Also, you can try subscribing to faulted\closing\closed events on the channel, maybe it will give you some clue.

Comment: @tzachs good advice, to be sure. I, as a rule, don't do Pokémon exception handling. I'm double-checking my codebase for exception-swallowing catch blocks.

Comment: OK, amazingly I have no good idea on how to proceed. My suggestion would be to set the debugger to break on CommObj.Close/Fault. That way you can see who calls that. If this is a prod environment you might be able to catch the responsible party by running PerfView for a long time in profiling mode. With a little luck there is a call stack that reveals the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the issue. An unmanaged component was blowing up and scribbling on memory. The CLR was able to (somewhat) mitigate the carnage, but the WCF exceptions were a red herring.